# Differentiating inside a conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables, and let $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y) = \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial x} (x,y)$ be functions.

Suppose that $\mathbb{E} \left( g(X,Y) \mid X \right) \leq 0$.

> > Can we say (either in general, or under fairly mild conditions) that $\mathbb{E} \left( f(X,Y) \mid X = x \right)$ is weakly decreasing in $x$?

Comment: Expectation (or conditional expectation) is an integration. Interchanging differentiation and integration is defined by Leibniz integral rule. Please see Theorem 5 and 6 in http://imai.princeton.edu/teaching/files/Expectation.pdf

Comment: @triomphe I am aware that expectation is an integration. It's not clear (to me) that conditional expectation is in general, however, so it's not obvious (to me) that the theorems you cite are relevant. Could you be more specific about what you mean when you say that conditional expectation is an integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, the conclusion is not always true.

For example, we can take f(x,y) = y - x, X is uniform on [0,1]. When $X < 0.5$, Y = 0, when $X \geq 0.5$, Y = 10000.

If we suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and we define $E[f(X,Y)|X=x] = E[f(X,Y)|X]_{X=x}$

then we have $E[f(X,Y)|X=x] = E[f(x,Y)]$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Now we are wondering if $E[f(x,Y)]$ is weakly decreasing, which is true in some conditions, such as $g$ is bounded

Comment: Thank you for this. Does the result hold in the case in which $X$ and $Y$ are negatively correlated? Your answer suggests that this might possibly be true.